# Best way to get future event from a date and a time attribute

Tags: python, django, datetime, date

In one of my Django application I have an object with both a date and a time attribute, and i don't wish to use a datetime single attribute.

For the sake of example let's call this object "Meeting":

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    publication_date = models.DateField()
    publication_time = models.TimeField()
```

Now I would like to get all the Meetings in the future given the current time

I am currently using this query:

> Meeting.objects.filter(publication_date__gte=datetime.date.today()).exclude(publication_date=
>   datetime.date.today(),
>   publication_time__lt =
>   datetime.datetime.now()).order_by('publication_date',
>   'publication_time')

But I feel like there might be a more efficient way

Comment: "i don't wish to use a datetime single attribute." How come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope that would be the correct way to do it given the constraint of not using a datetime field.  Why you don't want to use a datetime field I don't know.

Comment: I have some legacy code I have to deal with and an active database... but if they are no alternative, i will consider the merging option.